# 2D packing problem - how to optimise/maximise area of a a set of irregular convex polygons within a polygon?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons, packing-problem

I'm interested in a particular case of this problem: fitting odd-shaped polygons/shapes within the bounds of a rectangle.

Say you have 10 sticker designs and you want to fit them all on a sheet of A4 paper for printing. You can rotate and translate each sticker at will to fit the shapes around each other.

[image]

**My goal is to find the layout that allows me to maximise the size ("area"?) of each sticker**. A harder problem would allow weightings that would allow some stickers to be larger than average and some smaller but I'm more interested in the simpler problem.

**Is there any method or software for optimising the fit of the stickers within the bounding rectangle? I'm not expecting a perfect solution, just some way to get significantly better than random would be great.**

Comment: This is a 2D packing problem and you accumulate all difficulties: variable sizes and shapes, rotation allowed. There is no easy solution.

Comment: Even trying to fit identical circles into a square brings up unsolved problems, and you want to fit random shapes in a rectangle? By the way, the title says "convex polygons", but the stickers in the body are neither convex nor polygonal.

Comment: @Yves Daoust - of course, 2D packing but with different shapes. I don't need anything close to a solution but is there some algorithm or software that can produce better answers than I can myself?

Comment: @Gerry Myserson - I was hoping that would be simpler but might be wrong.

Comment: I have no idea what you can.